# Firebase preventing local code tampering?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Looking through the firebase docs, I was wondering how methods like `reauthenticateWithCredential` would prevent local tampering to say bring the code outside of that method, thus no longer requiring the reauth. Does firebase parse the local file to make sure it is unchanged? Or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using `reauthenticateWithCredential` for? Firebase Auth will require recent authentication for sensitive operations like email or password update. Firebase Auth will also invalidate sessions on big account changes requiring reauthentication.

For cases where you require reauthentication for sensitive operations like credit card change, shipping address change, etc, you would require recent authentication by checking the `auth_time` (this is the timestamp of the sign in operation) in the ID token and confirm it is recent (reauthentication updates that). So even if they bypass this from the client, your backend ID token verification or security rules will enforce that reauthentication was completed by checking the `auth_time`.

Comment: I had nothing in particular to use it for, was just wondering. Your answer does clear up my confusion though, thanks.